# Finding the value of θ using matrix algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Determine the values of θ for which the system of equations,

\begin{align}
 x + y +z &= 1\\
 x + 2y + 4z &= θ\\
 x + 4y + 10z &= θ^2\\
\end{align}

possesses a solution, and for each such value find all solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Note:
$$\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\1&2&4\\1&4&10\end{vmatrix}=0.$$
Hence:
$$\begin{vmatrix}1&1&1\\\theta&2&4\\\theta^2&4&10\end{vmatrix}=0 \Rightarrow \theta_{1,2}=1,2.$$

Comment: We have the same values for θ. I got 1 and 2, too. x=1, but I cannot find the solutions for y and z. Do you know?

Comment: You just solve a system of linear equations for the given thetas. For $\theta =1$, $(x,y,z)=(1,0,0)$ and for $\theta=2$, $(x,y,z)=(0,1,0)$.